# I get an error on my SAS code could I have assistance?

Tags: sas

When I run my code I get a error: ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order. I want to create a table with the input ID, default, student.

Here is my sample code. Could I have someone look at my code?

Code:

```
data have;
input ID  default student 
cards;
(1) yes    yes   
(2) Yes    No   
(3) NO    Yes   
(4) No     No   

;
run;
```

This is the error code I get:

```
 1          OPTIONS NONOTES NOSTIMER NOSOURCE NOSYNTAXCHECK;
 72         
 73         data have;
 74         input ID  default student
 75         cards;
 76         (1) yes    yes
            _
            180
 ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
 
 77         (2) Yes    No
 78         (3) NO    Yes
 79         (4) No     No
 80         
 81         ;
 82         run;
 
 ERROR: No DATALINES or INFILE statement.
 NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
 WARNING: The data set WORK.HAVE may be incomplete.  When this step was stopped there were 0 observations and 4 variables.
 WARNING: Data set WORK.HAVE was not replaced because this step was stopped.
 NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
       real time           0.00 seconds
       cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Comment: It is best to post the lines from the SAS log so that you can see exactly where in the code SAS has detected an issue.

Comment: This isn't required for the problem you posted yesterday, SAS will do the groupings by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input statement does not have a semi-colon to mark the end.  So you are reading a variable named CARDS as part of the INPUT statement.  So your lines of data are being seen as more SAS commands which is generating the error messages.

Once you fix that then you also need to fix your INPUT statement. You cannot read a string like `(1)` as a number.  But ID variables are normally never used in arithmetic anyway so just make it a character variable.  Strings like `yes` or `Yes` cannot be read as numbers either.

```
data have;
  input ID $ default $ student $;
cards;
(1) yes    yes   
(2) Yes    No   
(3) NO    Yes   
(4) No     No   
;
```

Comment: It looks like I do not need to input an ID.

Comment: If you want to read the line in simple list mode like your INPUT statement is doing your need to read that part of the line into something. Other choices are remove those characters from the in-line data lines. Or using `@` cursor movement in the INPUT statement to move past those characters.  `input @4 default $ student $;`

Comment: How about this? data have;
  input default $ student $;
cards;
 yes    yes   
 Yes    No   
 NO    Yes   
 No     No   
;

Comment: I cannot put  () for the ID?

Comment: I no idea what you are asking.  In the code in the answer the parentheses are part of the value of the string being read into the ID variable.